# Plot of mean square error [EDIT]

Tags: matlab, image-processing

If this be the formula for MSE for RGB images A,B of same size 256*200, then how to obtain a line plot for every pixel with x axis representing pixels and y axis representing the MSE values

MSE = reshape(mean(mean((double(A) - double(B)).^2,2),1),[1,3])

There are only two images A ,B. The plot should illustrate change between each pixel of A and B which is meant by MSE.

Comment: What do you mean by "number of pixels"? Do you actually have a series of differently-sized pairs of images, or what? I think you need to explain more about your problem before we can do much to help you solve it.

Comment: @Gareth: Edited the question as suggested.

Comment: So are you looking for a plot that has 256*200 points, one for every pixel of the image (in, let's say, raster order)? Or one with one point per image row (or per image column) showing mean-squared errors for individual rows/columns? Or something that's ordered by amount of error, showing the statistical distribution of errors? Sorry to pester, but it's still not at all clear to me what you're after...

Comment: @Gareth : No problem with your queries , after all I should be the one apologizing. The first option sounds ok. The plot should be for MSE vs pixels so that I should be able to see the error pattern(one point per image row (one for every pixel of the image).

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. First you say "The first option sounds OK" -- that was the one with one data point per pixel. Then you say "one point per image row", which is something else entirely. Then you say "one for every pixel of the image" again. And if you really plot a point for every pixel, your plot isn't showing *mean* squared errors any more anyway! At least one of us is confused...

Comment: One other thing: Is this homework?

Comment: Oh, wait, these are RGB images. Are you wanting to take the mean squared error over the three colour planes? If so, note that this is probably a bad idea: the result will not be very indicative of how big differences will look to the human eye. A change of given (absolute) size in the G plane will typically be much, much more visible than a similar change in the B plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display the changes "between each pixel" then what you're showing is not *mean* squared errors any more -- there's no averaging going on. (Unless you intend to average across the three colour planes, but I don't recommend that: changes in R,G,B are not equally salient to the human visual system. If you really must do this, you might want to weight them, say, 2:4:1 for something a bit more representative, but this is still ad hoc and not likely to give a very accurate idea of what differences will *look* biggest.)

Of course it's perfectly reasonable to want to see the per-pixel errors, but I wouldn't recommend using a line plot to display them; it's likely to be confusing rather than informative. Rather, display them as an image:

```
errs = (double(A)-double(B)).^2;
image(errs / max(errs(:)));
axis image;
```

which you can then compare by eye with `A` and `B` to see what image regions/features/... correspond to worse errors. The brightness and colour of each pixel indicate the amount of error and how it's distributed across the R, G, and B planes.

On the other hand, perhaps what you actually need is mean squared error over individual rows, or columns, of the image. In that case, after creating `errs` as above, use `mean` to compute the row or column means; that will give you a 256-by-1-by-3 image or a 1-by-200-by-3 image; now I would suggest plotting R,G,B curves separately unless you (probably foolishly in my opinion, as mentioned above) insist on averaging the planes.

```
row_errs = mean(errs,2); % this is now of size [n,1,3]
```

now `row_errs(:,:,1)` is a vector of MS-across-rows red errors, `row_errs(:,:,2)` is a vector of MS-across-rows green errors, etc. You can feed these to `plot`.

Comment: Apologize again for the confusion. From your assertive reply I have followed that I was interested to find mean squared error over individual rows for each color band. So, for this I need not display as an image. Hence, it would be kind of you to highlight what to be done. Thank you for your time & patience.

Comment: row_errs = mean(errs,2); plot(row_errs(:,:,1)); Please see if I have followed this part or not.(I) row_errs contains the mean of the matrix errs over the second the second dimension(column 2). (II)In the plot command, the x axis represents the number of pixels and y axis represents the MSE values. Also, there is an error which goes like this >>"Incomplete or misformed expression or statement" reslting out of the statement image(errs / max(errs(:)); This error however, goes away on commenting the statement. Would highly appreciate for your expert directions.thank you

Comment: Whoops, I missed off a closing parenthesis on the `errs / max(errs(:))` thing. Sorry about that. (I've now edited it into my answer.)